# Splitting large typescript file into module across multiple files

Tags: javascript, typescript

I currently have a large typescript file that I want to split up. There are a few functions and variables only used within the file, and a number of classes. It currently looks something along these lines:

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3];
function formatDate() {...}

class Widget { ... }
class Section { ... }
```

I've tried putting this in a module and splitting it across a few files:

```
//Widget.ts
module ReportTemplate {
    export class Widget { ... }
}

//Section.ts
module ReportTemplate {
    export class Section { ... }
}

//ReportTemplate.ts
/// <reference path="Widget.ts"/>
/// <reference path="Section.ts"/>
module ReportTemplate {
    var numbers = [1, 2, 3];
    function formatDate() { ... }
}
```

I was hoping that this would be equivalent to my original file, but wrapped in a module, but what I've found is that `Widget` and `Section` are unable to access `numbers` and `formatDate`.

I wasn't sure if I'd just misunderstood the references, so I've tried adding references to `ReportTemplate.ts` in `Section.ts` and `Widget.ts` but it hasn't helped. The only way I've found to allow `Section.ts` and `Widget.ts` to access `numbers` and `formatDate` is to export them, but I don't want them to be accessible outside the module.

I've read quite a bit about typescript modules, but I haven't found any examples that are the same as what I'm trying to do, so I'm still confused. Am I trying to do something which can't be done, or am I simply going about it the wrong way?

Comment: You're correct, if the namespace (internal module) members are not exported, they're not accessible in separate files.

Comment: Does this mean the [documentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules) is wrong? 
"Because we want the interfaces and classes here to be visible outside the module, we preface them with export."
"Even though the files are separate, they can each contribute to the same module and can be consumed as if they were all defined in one place."

This sounds to me like `export` is for making public outside the module, but is it actually for making public outside the file?

Comment: Because of the way namespaces are compiled, it's both. The namespace in each file is compiled separately, and at runtime each namespace builds upon the previous. During compilation, TypeScript knows where to get the members in the namespace, but the resulting JavaScript needs access to them at runtime, hence the export.  - The `"as if they were all defined in one place"` part is misleading though.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Presumably this means it's not possible to expose something to code which is within the same module but a different file, without also exposing it to code which it outside of the module?

Comment: Yup, that's right. One option is to use separate namespaces, and then have something like [gulp-umd](https://github.com/eduardolundgren/gulp-umd) wrap everything in another module, and then only export the namespace you want to.

Comment: TypeScript namespaces (aka modules) are each compiled separately into a different closure, even if their names are the same.  The only variables and functions that actually become visible in the namespace/module are `export`ed ones.  Non-`export`ed functions and variables stay within the closure.

Comment: Therefore, what you want is not possible.  You cannot refer to a private (i.e. non-`export`ed) variable/function inside the *same* namespace but that is defined separately, because that variable/function will be residing in a separate closure.  This has nothing to do with splitting into files.  Put all your code in the same file but define your namespace three times and it will be exactly the same.

Comment: This design is actually a *feature*.  Large libraries may add different functionalities under the same namespace, and you don't want internal implementation details of one feature to conflict with the implementation of another feature simply because they use the same private variable/function names.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest you move to the ES6 style of modules & imports. Instead of what is now called "namespaces" using the keyword `module`.

To adapt your example above do this...

```
//Widget.ts
export class Widget { ... }

//Section.ts
export class Section { ... }

//ReportTemplate.ts
import {Widget} from './Widget.ts';
import {Section} from './Section.ts';
var numbers = [1, 2, 3];
function formatDate() { ... }
function doStuff() {
  // use the classes you imported
  var widget = new Widget();
  var section = new Section();
}
```

You will have to tell tsc what module syntax to use, and target at least ES5:

```
//tsconfig.json
{
  "module": "common",
  "target": "ES5"
}
```

There was conversation regarding this change when it when into TypeScript **[here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/2923)**