# How to create and use custom classes in Ionic2/typescript

Tags: typescript, ionic2

I am new to OOP and typescript. I am working on Ionic2 project.

I have a page **list**

```
list
- list.html
- list.ts
- list.scss
```

I have create a new class/.ts file in same folder

```
export class TestClass{
    constructor(){
        console.log("I am test class");
    }
}
```

then In list.ts I use

```
import { Component,ViewChild,ElementRef,Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams,Platform,Content } from 'ionic-angular';

import {TestClass} from 'test.ts';

declare var Phaser:any;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-list',
  templateUrl: 'list.html'
})
export class ListPage {

  testClass:any = new TestClass();

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private _platform:Platform) {


  };
};//end class
```

this give me error `Cannot find module "test.ts"`

How can i import my custom class in Ionic2 page?

Please help.

Comment: First rule of TypeScript: It does not add OOP to JavaScript. Rather, it adds a powerful structural type system for expressing the shapes of apis. The type system in TS is more functional than OO in most respects.

Comment: Also this code: `testClass: any = new TestClass();` is insane.

Comment: Dear @AluanHaddad, I dont have much OOP exposure, I just try to use this  link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32847337/splitting-large-typescript-file-into-module-across-multiple-files

Comment: My point is that TypeScript is not about OOP, it is about _typing_ all paradigms present in JS. Also please, please never write `testClass: any = new TestClass();`. Write `testClass = new TestClass();` instead, otherwise you might as well not use TypeScript.

Comment: In typescript, remember to always include external files/modules using `./` if they are in the same folder of the file you are including them from. Not using `./` means to ask to node.js to resolve the module in `node_modules`, which is the folder where node modules are actually stored. This rule applies to every single javascript project really, but in your case (and in Ionic2) it's pretty important.

Comment: Dear AluanHaddad, briosheje , thanks for your help and suggestions, I will keep these points remembered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First remove the back ticks `.
Second create a file in the same folder named test.ts.
Third paste the code export class TestClass...
Finally `import {TestClass} from './test';` using `./`

Comment: actually you dont need the '.ts' extension either

Comment: If I don't add ./ the IntelliSense of Visual Studio Code marks the import as an error..

Comment: Back ticks are pasted just by mistake, not part of original file, & file name is test.ts, it is in same folder as list.ts. I have edited in the question. But still getting same error.

Comment: Did you remove the extension .ts?