# How to use a custom class in ionic 2/typescript

Tags: ionic2

I added a custom style in my `variables.scss` to change my `alert` but I'm not sure how I can apply this. I already saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43775130/how-to-create-and-use-custom-classes-in-ionic2-typescript) but it did not help me. Do I have to put this in my `typescript`? If yes, how?

my `variabless.scss`

```
.alert-wrapper {
  border-radius: 13px;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 270px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

my `html` calling the alert

```
<button ion-button color="babydanger" (click)="showCheckbox()">SIGN UP</button>
```

my `.ts`

```
showCheckbox() {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create();
    alert.setTitle('Which planets have you visited?');

    alert.addInput({
      type: 'checkbox',
      label: 'Alderaan',
      value: 'value1',
      checked: true
    });

    alert.addInput({
      type: 'checkbox',
      label: 'Bespin',
      value: 'value2'
    });
```

Comment: so do you want the custom style to override all of your alerts or only some in some pages? can you share more of context what you want to achieve

Comment: @SergeyRudenko yes. all alerts

Comment: so depending on what you need to change you may want to check this resource and potentially just override the values for scss vars: https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/